# Scheduling cronjobs at specified time

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have scheduled some jobs in **crontab** which are to be run one by one, at some specific time. My script for crontab is :

```
15 10 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh
45 11 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchGC.sh
15 13 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_FF.sh
45 14 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_GC.sh
15 16 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_FF.sh
45 17 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_GC.sh
```

These scripts ideally should start at 10:15, 11:45, 13:15, 14:45, and so on.
But the scripts are not starting as expected, rather they start at 10:15, 10:15, 10:16, 10:16, 10:17, 10:17.
These scripts are writing some log files also.
I am running it in Apple McBook Air, with OS X 12.4.0 Darwin

Comment: Is that the exact output you get from `crontab -l`?  Just asking because at first sight the crontab definition looks right, but maybe the file got clobbered somehow, and what cron sees might not be what you intended to send it.

Comment: Yes its the exact output what I see after executing `crontab -l`

Comment: Are you sure that each of your scripts does not call the next one  in the order you regarded?